# Deformed arrow head bug in version 13.0.1.0

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

There is a bug in version 13.0.1.0 - head of an arrow pointing exactly along z-axis is deformed. **Is it present also in newer versions?**

A workaround is to add `{10^-16, 0, 0}` to the last point of the arrow so that its direction is not exactly along z-axis.

```
SystemInformation["Kernel"][[1 ;; 2]]
Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.1], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 0.05]], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 0.05]], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, 0.05]], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1/4, 1/4, 1/4}, {1/4, 1/4, 1}}, 0.05]]}, 
 PlotRange -> 1]
Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.1], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 0.05]], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 0.05]], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1} + {10^-16, 0, 0}}, 0.05]], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1/4, 1/4, 
      1/4}, {1/4, 1/4, 1} + {10^-16, 0, 0}}, 0.05]]}, PlotRange -> 1]

(* {"Version" -> 
  "13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)", 
 "ReleaseID" -> "13.0.1.0 (7620973, 2022012812415)"} *)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Work fine on  `"12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 24, 2021)"` and  `"13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work in 13.1.

Your code with the view points corresponding to your pictures:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the whole version number?

Comment: "13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"